# ArcPY Insert Cursor with data validation or 'remove duplicates' type of functionality

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm looking to build a script/GP tool with ArcPy that allows a user to submit a table to be loaded into an existing feature class (essentially an append/insert type of operation. However, I would like to have the table 'reviewed' first for duplicates: in this case duplicates being defined by a concatenation of several fields to create a unique ID.

In doing my prelimianary search here, this was quite close:
[Removing duplicates before inserting into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231575/removing-duplicates-before-inserting-into-database)

The target could be a SQL table, but the proposed solutions all refer to queries within SQL. My solution needs to be web-based and I'm most comfortable with Python. Is there a way to expose the underlying DB queries/constraints/indexes as suggested in the above link via ArcPy/Python?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little vague. You'll need to make sure that adding tabular data to your feature class makes sense, but there are a number of ways to approach this. I'm presuming you're using 10.x ArcGIS (i.e., arcpy, not gp).

You can use

```
arcpy.Frequency_analysis(in_table, out_table, frequency_fields;frequency_fields..., {summary_fields;summary_fields...})
```

and then see if there are any records where frequency exceeds 1, maybe using something like:

```
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(out_table, 'out_tableTV', '"FREQUENCY" > 1')
numEvents=int(arcpy.GetCount_management('out_tableTV'))
if numEvents > 0:
    print 'duplicates'
```

Alternatively, you can extract your values to a python list object, create a set from that (which eliminates duplicates), and the compare the list and set objects.

```
>>> x=[1,2,1]
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
>>> y=set(x)
>>> type(y)
<type 'set'>
>>> y
set([1, 2])
>>> if x!=y:
...     print 'duplicates exist'
...     
duplicates exist
```